# Ошибка при установке даты vuejs-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

Всем привет,

В laravel 5.5/vuejs 2.5 проекте использую пикер даты https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker 
также установив https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-momentjs и в resources/assets/js/app.js :

```
import moment from "moment";
Vue.use(require('vue-moment')); 

import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
```

И в темплейте :

```
<template>
    <section>
        <span>{{ new Date() | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }}</span> // Текущяя дата выводится правильно
...


<datepicker v-model="newTask.date_start.date" id="date_start" :format="customFormatter" :required=true
            :bootstrapStyling=true :clear-button=true></datepicker>
<span v-show="vueErrorsList.has('date_start')" class="text-danger">{{ vueErrorsList.first('date_start') }}</span>
    ...
    mounted() {
        this.setTaskDefaultValue();
    },  // mounted() {
    ...

        methods:{

            setTaskDefaultValue() {
               ...
                this.newTask.date_start= { //Получаю ошибку Error in render: "ReferenceError: moment is not defined"
                    date: new Date(2016, 9,  11)
                }; // Если эти 3 строки закоментарить то ошибки нет

            customFormatter(date) {
                return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
//                return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
            },
    ...
```

В системе имею :

```
$ composer show
barryvdh/laravel-debugbar             v3.1.0  PHP Debugbar integration for Laravel
dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir              0.1     implementation of xdg base directory specification for php
doctrine/annotations                  v1.6.0  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                        v1.7.1  Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                  v1.5.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                       v2.8.1  Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                         v2.6.3  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/inflector                    v1.3.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                 1.1.0   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                        v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
egulias/email-validator               2.1.3   A library for validating emails against several RFCs
erusev/parsedown                      1.6.4   Parser for Markdown.
facebook/webdriver                    1.5.0   A PHP client for Selenium WebDriver
fideloper/proxy                       3.3.4   Set trusted proxies for Laravel
filp/whoops                           2.1.14  php error handling for cool kids
fzaninotto/faker                      v1.7.1  Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you.
guzzlehttp/psr7                       1.4.2   PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods
hamcrest/hamcrest-php                 v2.0.0  This is the PHP port of Hamcrest Matchers
intervention/image                    2.4.1   Image handling and manipulation library with support for Laravel integration
jakub-onderka/php-console-color       0.1    
jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter v0.3.2 
laracasts/utilities                   3.0     Transform your PHP to JavaScript
laravel/dusk                          v2.0.8  Laravel Dusk provides simple end-to-end testing and browser automation.
laravel/framework                     v5.5.29 The Laravel Framework.
laravel/tinker                        v1.0.3  Powerful REPL for the Laravel framework.
laravelcollective/html                v5.5.1  HTML and Form Builders for the Laravel Framework
league/flysystem                      1.0.41  Filesystem abstraction: Many filesystems, one API.
maximebf/debugbar                     v1.14.1 Debug bar in the browser for php application
mockery/mockery                       1.0     Mockery is a simple yet flexible PHP mock object framework for use in unit testing with PHPUnit, PHPSpec or any other testing framework. Its core goal is to offer a test double framework...
monolog/monolog                       1.23.0  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
mtdowling/cron-expression             v1.2.1  CRON for PHP: Calculate the next or previous run date and determine if a CRON expression is due
myclabs/deep-copy                     1.7.0   Create deep copies (clones) of your objects
nesbot/carbon                         1.22.1  A simple API extension for DateTime.
nikic/php-parser                      v3.1.3  A PHP parser written in PHP
paragonie/random_compat               v2.0.11 PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
patricktalmadge/bootstrapper          5.10.2  Twitter Bootstrap markup generator
phar-io/manifest                      1.0.1   Component for reading phar.io manifest information from a PHP Archive (PHAR)
phar-io/version                       1.0.1   Library for handling version information and constraints
phpdocumentor/reflection-common       1.0.1   Common reflection classes used by phpdocumentor to reflect the code structure
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock     4.2.0   With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via DocBlocks or otherwise retrieve information that is embedded in a DocBlock.
phpdocumentor/type-resolver           0.4.0  
phpspec/prophecy                      1.7.3   Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage             5.3.0   Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage information.
phpunit/php-file-iterator             1.4.5   FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-text-template             1.2.1   Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                     1.0.9   Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream              2.0.2   Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                       6.5.5   The PHP Unit Testing framework.
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects          5.0.6   Mock Object library for PHPUnit
psr/container                         1.0.0   Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/http-message                      1.0.1   Common interface for HTTP messages
psr/log                               1.0.2   Common interface for logging libraries
psr/simple-cache                      1.0.0   Common interfaces for simple caching
psy/psysh                             v0.8.17 An interactive shell for modern PHP.
pusher/pusher-php-server              v3.0.1  Library for interacting with the Pusher REST API
ramsey/uuid                           3.7.2   Formerly rhumsaa/uuid. A PHP 5.4+ library for generating RFC 4122 version 1, 3, 4, and 5 universally unique identifiers (UUID).
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup    1.0.1   Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                  2.1.2   Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                        2.0.1   Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                 3.1.0   Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                    3.1.0   Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state                2.0.0   Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/object-enumerator           3.0.3   Traverses array structures and object graphs to enumerate all referenced objects
sebastian/object-reflector            1.1.1   Allows reflection of object attributes, including inherited and non-public ones
sebastian/recursion-context           3.0.0   Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/resource-operations         1.0.0   Provides a list of PHP built-in functions that operate on resources
sebastian/version                     2.0.1   Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
solbeg/laravel-vue-validation         1.0.3   Extends Bootstrapper package. It automatically converts Laravel's request rules into Vee's rules.
spatie/db-dumper                      2.8.1   Dump databases
spatie/laravel-backup                 5.1.3   A Laravel 5 package to backup your application
spatie/temporary-directory            1.1.3   Easily create, use and destroy temporary directories
swiftmailer/swiftmailer               v6.0.2  Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/console                       v3.4.3  Symfony Console Component
symfony/css-selector                  v4.0.3  Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/debug                         v3.4.3  Symfony Debug Component
symfony/event-dispatcher              v4.0.3  Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/finder                        v3.4.3  Symfony Finder Component
symfony/http-foundation               v3.4.3  Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                   v3.4.3  Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/polyfill-mbstring             v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php70                v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/process                       v3.4.3  Symfony Process Component
symfony/routing                       v3.4.3  Symfony Routing Component
symfony/translation                   v3.4.3  Symfony Translation Component
symfony/var-dumper                    v3.4.3  Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
theseer/tokenizer                     1.1.0   A small library for converting tokenized PHP source code into XML and potentially other formats
tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles     2.2.1   CssToInlineStyles is a class that enables you to convert HTML-pages/files into HTML-pages/files with inline styles. This is very useful when you're sending emails.
twbs/bootstrap                        v3.3.7  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
vlucas/phpdotenv                      v2.4.0  Loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` automagically.
wboyz/laravel-enum                    v0.2.1  Base enum class with some features.
webmozart/assert                      1.2.0   Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
```

Неправилен формат или в чем проблема?

Спасибо !

Comment: чет я не понял в чем проблема в том что сохранять дату не хочет ? попробуй формат поменять на YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Нет я хочу установить дефолтовое значение при открытии формы

Comment: Если поменять формат в customFormatter на YYYY-MM-DD - не помогло и та же ошибка

Comment: newTask.date_start.date так а у тебя этот объект есть  ?

Comment: Я как раз и хотел проинициализировать  
newTask.date_start по примеру.
Но видимо неправильно. Непонятно как правильно ?

Comment: Создай в секции `data(){return newTask={date_start: moment().format()}}` попроубй так а `<datepicker v-model="newTask.date_start" id="date_start" :format="customFormatter" :required=true
            :bootstrapStyling=true :clear-button=true></datepicker>`